# How to parse the key and get its value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am opening a URL from javascript. I need to look for the term "colour: x" and then retrieve the value x.

```
request.get("URL", function (error, res, body)

val = body.indexOf('colour') -> works
```

which means that web page has the string "colour".

Web page looks like this

```
size: 8 colour: 1
```

So, Here I need to retrieve the value of the key 'colour'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To search for a pattern in any general text:

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) if you know how your information is written.

This regular expression should do the job :

```
/\bcolour:\s+(\d+)/
```

(the word "colour:" followed by any space, and then by any number of digits (`\d+`).

It *captures* the digits, so this will be the value of the first capture group (`found[1]`) in my example.

```js
body = `size: 8 colour: 1`
    
let regex = /\bcolour:\s+(\d+)/;
let found = body.match(regex);

console.log(found[1]);
```

In the case there is no match (i.e., no 'colour: xx' in the page), the `found` result will be `null`, so you should of course check for it before, for safety.

```js
    body = `size: 8 but unfortunately, no colour here`
        
    let regex = /\bcolour:\s+(\d+)/;
    let found = body.match(regex);

    //console.log(found[1]); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    
    // This snippet below is safe to use :
    if (found) {
       console.log(found[1]);
    } else {
       console.log('not found');
    }
```